# Can the electric potential corresponding to the negative plate ever be equal to anything bigger than zero?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential-energy

I am doing my homework.
I read my textbook. It says that the negatively charged plate is the low potential plate. It also shows a example of lower plate equal to 0V, I guess for simplicity.

But what intrigues me is when I do the question, almost every one of them, it is safe to assume the lower plate to be equal to 0V.

Is it always 0? When is it safe to assume?

Comment: The zero of potential is arbitrary...

Comment: @dmckee, I know its arbitrary when calculating the difference but not for absolute value?

Comment: The point is that there *isn't* a single well defined value. You really are free to *pick* the value of potential for one point, and all other are then computed relative your choice. As with gravitational potential problems there are some customary choices. Can you guess what one of the customs is? But what happens to that custom when you introduce two [batteries|capacitors|other things with a "negative plate"]?

Comment: @dmckee, well with gravity you always measure from the lowest an object could possibly fall. It's the same for electric. But can the lowest point for potential be outside the plates?

Answer (score 0):

It's s not always 0, but it is safe to assume that it is the relative difference between the plates that is important, not the absolute value.